# Background agent task is never executed in Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, live-tile

I have a background agent that i would like to be executed in Mango for updating the live tile.
The problem is that it is never executed.
Here is the code that i used:

```
//start background agent 
PeriodicTask periodicTask = new PeriodicTask("BruceWpAgent");

periodicTask.Description = "BruceWp periodic live task";
periodicTask.ExpirationTime = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

// If the agent is already registered with the system,
if (ScheduledActionService.Find(periodicTask.Name) != null)
{
     ScheduledActionService.Remove("BruceWpAgent");
}

ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
```

I've found my app name between that Apps that use background jobs but the task is never invoked.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where is assignment of your agent to `periodicTask`?

Comment: PeriodicTask periodicTask = new PeriodicTask("BruceWpAgent");  is it the error?

Comment: How are you verifying that it's never called? and not just an error in your task code? Can you please confirm the name of your agent too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code may help you..

```
string periodicTaskName = "PeriodicAgent";      
    public bool agentsAreEnabled = true;
    private void StartBackgroundAgent()
    {
        // Variable for tracking enabled status of background agents for this app.
        agentsAreEnabled = true;
        // Obtain a reference to the period task, if one exists
        periodicTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(periodicTaskName) as PeriodicTask;

        // If the task already exists and background agents are enabled for the
        // application, you must remove the task and then add it again to update 
        // the schedule
        if (periodicTask != null)
        {
            RemoveAgent(periodicTaskName);
        }

        periodicTask = new PeriodicTask(periodicTaskName);

        // The description is required for periodic agents. This is the string that the user
        // will see in the background services Settings page on the device.
        periodicTask.Description = "Task to update the Economic times tile.";

        // Place the call to Add in a try block in case the user has disabled agents
        try
        {
            ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
            // If debugging is enabled, use LaunchForTest to launch the agent in one minute.

            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
            if (exception.Message.Contains("BNS Error: The action is disabled"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Background agents for this application have been disabled by the user.");
                agentsAreEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this hands on lab for [Adding Multitasking to Your Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh220584) in Windows Phone 7.5, that should cover it.